# What does ^--- With additional stack trace in a mocha test mean?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sequelize.js

I have a node.js project that is using mocha for it's testing. My most recent test that utilizes Sequelizes `create()` function for adding a row to a table now produces this message instead of the stack trace that I have always seen up until now...

```
    1) Should be able to store a player's name
^--- With additional stack trace: Error: [object SequelizeInstance]
```

I am unable to find any additional stack trace info.  The log files contain no information.  Any idea why this is occurring, and how I can view the stack trace?

Comment: That error makes it should like you are passing a non-error as an error. e.g. Expecting a callback to be `function(err, instance)` and it is actually `function(instance)`. But that's just a guess.

Comment: That is exactly what this was!  It was the `find()` call I was making after `create()` to test that it was working.  Had it expecting `(err, instance)`.  Want to submit this as an answer so I can give you credit @loganfsmyth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Error: [object SequelizeInstance]` to me says that somewhere you are doing `new Error(result)`. The simplest way that could happen is if you have a callback like

```
function(err, result){
```

that is actually supposed to be

```
function(result){
```

so I would check your callbacks and ensure that they all actually match the expected signature. Most callbacks in node use the two-param format, but not all.